# why git reset --hard and push --force doesn't revert my remote branch

Tags: git, push, reset

I have a branch named `hfix`. I have some dirty commits on the `origin/hfix`. When I issue the command below:

```
git reset --hard abd000b3ce70557f05a469d580fc8f3bf1c3a8b2
```

My local head pointer moves backward where I want it to be. Now what I want to do is to force my remote branch have the same history as my local so I issue:

```
git push --force origin hfix
```

But I get the following error:

```
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/hfix (you should pull first)
To root@172.16.131.9:/var/local/fxxx/local_core.repo
 ! [remote rejected] hfix -> hfix (non-fast-forward)
```

**I dont want to pull**, as it will make my local like the remote one. What should I do to clean the remote branch as my local one?

Answer (score 2):

Your remote repository has most likely `denyNonFastforwards = true` in its config. If you switch that to false , `git push --force origin hfix`  should then work as you expect .

Comment: in `~/.gitconfig` on my server not local there is no such a thing as `denyNonFastforwards`

Comment: Sorry to ask: when we don't have that parameter does that mean that it has been set to true by default and I should set it to false?

Comment: git config --global receive.denyNonFastForwards false

Comment: It's not just _your_ `.gitconfig`, it's the system config and the repository config that matter as well.